# How to determine flatness

Tags: commutative-algebra, flatness

Let $k$ be a field and define $R=k[x,y]/(xy)$ and an $R$-Algebra $A=k[x]\times k[y]=R/(y)\times R/(x)$. I have to answer two questions

1. Is $k[x]=R/(y)$ flat over $A$
2. Is $A$ flat over $R$

I don't necessarily need the answer but I don't know where to start with both these questions. I do know the definition of flatness but is there a way to not use exact sequences with tensor products? Or is that the only way? So any hint is appreciated.

Edit: As suggested by someone: We closely follow the book of Atiyah and Macdonald introduction to commutative algebra and we are in chapter 4.

Comment: You need to put more information about what you know and what tools you're familiar with in the post, otherwise you're going to get responses that assume things you don't know (like the answer below).

Answer (score 0):

Since you only wanted a hint:

1. Lemma: Projective modules are flat.
2. Lemma: If $I$ is an ideal of a commutative ring $R$ and $R \to R/I$ is flat, then $I = I^2$.

Comment: 1) We have not defined projective modules so I don't think I can use that
2) I thought about that but what would be $R$ and what $I$ and this situation? Since if $R=R$ and $I=A$ then I don't see how you compute $I^2$ or what it means to have $R/I$ since all elements of $R$ are linear combinations of powers of $x, y$ but $I$ is the direct product